# Adding data line by line in file in Unix

Tags: unix

I am extracting file names from one command it returns many file names and i am putting them into one file
code :

```
echo `find ${FILE_SYSTEM}/${dir_name}/${sub_dir_name} -type f -size +${BADFILES_SIZE} -exec ls -1lutr {} \; | sort -rn | awk '{print $9}'` >> Somefile.txt
```

The problem here is that i am not getting file names on each line.
Its giving two filenames on 1 line.
But i want to have each filename on 1 line.

Eg :

```
/informatica/ETD/PC9/scripts/kamil/temp/temp1.txt /informatica/ETD/PC9/scripts/kamil/temp/temp2.txt
```

I am getting filenames as shown above and i want as shown below.

```
/informatica/ETD/PC9/scripts/kamil/temp/temp1.txt
/informatica/ETD/PC9/scripts/kamil/temp/temp2.txt
```

Please give ur suggestions,

Comment: Replace the `\;` with `+` if your version of `find` supports it; it is a lot more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `echo` and backticks.  Don't!  The `echo` flattens all its arguments (a list of two files, it seems) into a single line of output.

Wrong:

```
echo `find ${FILE_SYSTEM}/${dir_name}/${sub_dir_name} -type f -size +${BADFILES_SIZE} -exec ls -1lutr {} \; | sort -rn | awk '{print $9}'` >> Somefile.txt
```

Right:

```
find ${FILE_SYSTEM}/${dir_name}/${sub_dir_name} -type f \
     -size +${BADFILES_SIZE} -exec ls -1lutr {} + |
sort -rn |
awk '{print $9}' >> Somefile.txt
```